# Angular js How to pass parameters to $location.path() and use this in $routeProvider for routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

On button click I have code to navigate.

---

```
$s.onClick = function (pageObj) {
     $location.path('/Next');
}
```

Here param pageObj is object containing link (ex: http://sample..), title and other key values. Now I want to pass link, title as params to $location.path so I tried with

---

```
$location.path('/Next/' + pageObj.link + '/' + pageObj.title)
```

Here link, title params I want to use in next page. pageObj.link is again http so the complete routing url will be invalid to navigate.

Here is the code for routing

---

```
angularModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/www/temp/Main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
    })
    .when('/Next', {

        templateUrl: '/www/temp/Select.html',
        controller: 'SelectController'

    })
});
```

how to check for params and navigate to Next page with those params. I do not want those params to be shown in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the parameters to appear in the URL, the absolute easiest way is to use the `$rootScope` like this:

**First Page**

```
$rootScope.routeParams.link = "/my/link/here";
$rootScope.routerParams.title = "My page title here";
```

**Second Page**

```
$scope.link = $rootScope.routerParams.link;
$scope.title = $rootScope.routerParams.title;
```

**Note**

You'll need to define the `$rootScope.routeParams` object in your `app.config`, similar to this:

```
app.config(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.routeParams = {
        link: null,
        title: null
    }
});
```

You'll also need to inject `$rootScope` into each controller where you reference it, similar to this:

```
app.controller('FirstPage_Ctrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.routeParams.link = "/my/link/here";
    $rootScope.routerParams.title = "My page title here";
});
```

Comment: I dont want to use $rootScope. My requirement is to send param through $location